# Change the color of three first letters in awesome CV (posquito) from red to blue

Tags: color, awesome-cv

I am currently using [Posquito's CV template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv) however I can not change the color from red to blue. In `awesome-cv.cls`, line 148, I changed the setting `\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}` to `skyblue` but without success. Any tip would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: Change `\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}` in line 142 to `\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{0395DE}`. Make sure that you ate editing the file that is later been used by LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4):

The main colour theme used throughout `awesome-cv`'s documents is the colour `awesome`. It can be `\colorlet` to `awesome-red` for a red theme, or something else for a different theme. For example, just add

```
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue}
```

before `\begin{document}` in your main `resume.tex` file to use the `skyblue` theme:

[image]

Here's what it looks like with `\colorlet{awesome}{purple}` (the colour `purple` is not defined by `awesome-cv`, but is loaded as one of the default colours with [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)):

[image]

Here's what it looks like with 60% orange (`\colorlet{awesome}{orange!60}`):

[image]